# How to view the size of the binary files using linux command?

Tags: linux, files, size

I have the binary file `csimu` under the following path `/data/local/tools/bin`.

I checked the size of the binary file using `du -sh csimu`, but it shows size as 0. But I have binary contents inside the file.

How can I check the size of the binary file using linux command in the terminal?

Comment: What is the size of the file reported by `ls -l`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe this will work

```
 stat -c %s  /data/local/tools/bin/csimu
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ls -lh FileName
```

Output

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 user user 5.2K Dec 26 17:08 FileName
```

I hope this is useful for you.